Confused with using generic constraints
const testObj = { x: 10, y: "Hello", z: true };

function getProperty<T>(obj: T, key: keyof T) {
  return obj[key];
}

const xValue = getProperty(testObj, 'x');
// const xValue: string | number | boolean

In the above code key: keyof T should mean that key is of type x|y|z
const testObj = { x: 10, y: "Hello", z: true };

function getProperty<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K) {
  return obj[key];
}

const xValue = getProperty(testObj, 'x');
// const xValue: number

In the above code, K extends keyof T should mean that K is a subtype with type x|y|z.
The way I see it, both are equivalent. Then why does the second block of code returns a more specific type?

Look at the inferred return type of the function declaration, and in particular the inferred type parameters of the function call.

@Bergi In inferred type parameters of fuction call, key for first is 'x'|'y'|'z' and of the second is x. My question is why aren't they same? Isn't keyof T as well as K extends keyof T same?

TypeScript doesn't synthesize generic type parameters for you. You need to annotate the generics yourself.  If T is inferred as {x: number, y: string, z: boolean}, then key is of type keyof T which is "x" | "y" | "z". That's the type you gave it. If you want it to be some subtype of keyof T inferred from the argument passed in for key, then you need to make it generic, like K extends keyof T. Which, when you do it, works as you desire. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a suitable duplicate. If not, what am I missing?

@jcalz Doesn't K extends keyof T mean that type of K is "x" | "y" | "z"?

@vinDev In the first call, the type of the key parameter is keyof typeof testObj, based on what T was inferred to. In the second call, the type is whatever K is inferred to, as long as it extends keyof T.

@vinDev not exactly, no. It means that K is constrained to "x" | "y" | "z". It can be more specific than that type, such as just "x".  Generics are type variables. They can be more specific than the thing they're constrained to.  Does this make sense yet or is something still missing?

@jcalz  If key: keyof T is like saying a=c, then isn't declaring K extends keyof T and then assigning it to key is same as saying a=b=c? Doesn't both ultimately mean the same?

No, it’s saying a=b≤c. Does that make sense now?
